# ApacheDS embedding into an application getting [LDAP: error code 2 - PROTOCOL_ERROR: The server will disconnect!]

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I have embedded ApacheDS LDAP server version 1.5.7 with a java-maven application . I was able to start the LDAP server programmatically . However when I tried to add a user to the LDAP using apache LDAP ApacheDirectoryStudio-linux-x86_64-2.0.0.v20130628 I am getting an error from the  server side. And then I upgraded the LDAP server to 1.5.8,2.0.0-M16-SNAPSHOT and downgraded to 1.5.5 and retried the same scenario every time server starts programmatically as usual however when trying add an user I am always getting the same error.  Any solution for this?

Errors and configurations are as follows below.

server side :  ERROR {org.apache.directory.shared.asn1.ber.grammar.AbstractGrammar} -  ERR_00001 Bad transition from state START_STATE, tag 0x74

ldap browser: Error while creating entry - [LDAP: error code 2 - PROTOCOL_ERROR: The server will disconnect!]

pom.xml dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- shared-ldap-schema module needs to be excluded to avoid multiple schema resources on the classpath-->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.directory.shared</groupId>
                <artifactId>shared-ldap-schema</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Environment: 
Ubuntu 12.10 , 
apache-maven-3.0.5, 
java version "1.6.0_24"